# How to edit in 4 spaces but save in 2 spaces?

Tags: coding-style, notepad++, indentation, code-formatting

There's a developer that I want to work with. His code is all written with 2 spaces as indentation.

*I hate the prospect of editing code with two columns of indentation.*

My coding style is tab, but it is irrelevant to me, what I want is 4 columns, and I never cared about the tabs vs. spaces war in my personal projects but now I have to not only read but also write in 2 spaces.

I'm talking about regular PHP/JS files and my editor of choice is Notepad++, but I'd switch for this project if there's an editor that allows me to:

- Edit and open code files with 2 spaces of indentation as if they had 4 spaces or one tab.
- Save such files with indentation of 2 spaces.

Again, the whole point here is that **I want 4 columns, he wants 2, and he does not use tabs.**

Comment: @evilotto We're friends, and we mostly agree about everything else but a few things. I'm ok with all his other style quirks, but the two spaces for indentation is the only thing that really sucks, and who knows, maybe there's a software solution to this human problem.

Comment: I would say don't bother, some solutions (like this one i suspect) create more problems than they solve.

But as for a solution: sounds like you are a programmer, so why not roll your own tool to replaces line prefixes 2-spaces to 4-spaces (or tab) and vice versa. If at the sime time replacing "/*ident2*/" with "/*ident4*/" you can raise an error when the latter expected identX value is not found. 
Good for batch processing, you could even pipe "dir /s > ident42.exe" or something similar. Dont forget to backup before having code mutate sourcecode..

Comment: @user2096041 This would require running a tool at every commit, so it would be a very crappy experience. If some editor had this, I would try it out just because of such feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be satisfied with Notepad++'s NPPAutoIndent plugin. It allows you to customize your indentations, allowing you to auto-indent with your choice of how many tabs or spaces. You might also get good use out of the TextFX plugin, which deals heavily with spacing.

This isn't exactly what you're trying to achieve, but at least this will solve the problem of coding habits. With this solution you would just have to learn to adjust your eyes to 2-space code. I looked around and couldn't find anything more specific to your needs.

You might also consider Eclipse IDE and look around at some plugins for it. It's highly configurable from the start, with many plugins adding even more customization options.

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion, but AFAIK NP++ already indents the following line as the previous one was (albeit I have installed Notepad# plugin so it might be a feature of it instead). And regarding Eclipse, I'd give it a look if there's actualy a plugin for it that does this, but all-around it's a horrible IDE IMHO, slower than Visual Studio and with less features, and worse "default experience" (without plugins).